# How to download Protocol Buffers v3 from this site?

Tags: go

I'm following this tutorial to install Protocol Buffers v3:

```
https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/go.html#install-grpc
```

It says "The simplest way to do this is to download pre-compiled binaries for your platform", what is "platform" here? Operating System or Programming Languages? Im confused at this step, because I dont understand what its saying exactly.

I even tried to follow the link but there is no Protobuf installation for "GoLang" at all, I can see java, python, linux, win, osx etc and I dont know which one to choose and this added to my frustration:

```
http://prntscr.com/nf2qye
```

Even if I download the file somehow then how and exactly where do I unzip in Linux?

Even if I unzip it somewhere then what will be the code to write in the bash_profile to update the environment variable PATH to include the path to the protoc binary file as mentioned in the tutorial?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that binary is OS dependent and contains the protoc compiler to compile the protobuffs.

> protoc-3.6.0-linux-x86_64.zip

Note: 3.6.0 is not the latest version

you will find all the binary [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases?after=conformance-build-tag)

download the zip, unzip and copy that protoc bin to

```
/usr/local/bin
```

run below commands for Linux:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/protoc && \
        wget https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-linux-x86_64.zip && \
        unzip protoc-3.6.0-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc3 && \
        cp protoc3/bin/* /usr/local/bin/ && \
        cp -R protoc3/include/* /usr/local/include && \
        chmod +x /usr/local/bin/protoc && \
        rm -rf /tmp/protoc
```

just type protoc in the terminal, it should work.

For go lang code generation, you have to download code generator separately.
i,e;

> protoc-gen-go.

install go and set the GOPATH.

then, run below command :

```
go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

After that, you could use go code generator plugin to generate the code like below:

```
protoc -I . hello.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:out
```

Comment: Before seeing your answer I tried downloading and extracting and now my /hom/username/bin folder contains this: http://prntscr.com/nf3f0m And the /home/username/ folder looks like this: http://prntscr.com/nf3ffw  Is everything right here?

Comment: you need to download the protoc-gen-go separately, otherwise it won't work. Only for golang, the code generator is not packaged with protoc bin. I have modified the steps, just have a look.

Comment: I think I installed protoc-gen-go using some command from some website, I tried to compile a test.proto file and it compiled successfully. Im okay here now or did I do something which will come back to bite in my _ later?